# jQuery button doesnt work on first click after value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

So, I am checking localStorage to see if certain key exists, if so, then I change buttons value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(localStorage.length);
    ProductName = $("#ProductNameHidden").text();
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage.key(i) == ProductName) {
            document.getElementById("SubmitButton").value = "GO TO CART";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("SubmitButton").value = "ADD TO CART";
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on button, nothing happens first time, only when I click it second time.

```
if (document.getElementById("SubmitButton").value == "GO TO CART") {
    $("#SubmitButton").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "Cart.html"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be,

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "GO TO CART") {
    window.location.href = "Cart.html"
  }
});
```